# Detox tests running locally but not in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, detox, azure-yaml-pipelines

When running our detox tests locally everything is working as expected. When running the detox test via the Azure pipeline we get a timeout error (see below). The pipeline has worked in the past, but it is now broken. We have used the troubleshooting guidelines but could use some recommendations on what the issue could be. Is it because of the React Native version we are using? Do we need to upgrade our detox version? What versions of React Native does detox support?

[Pipeline error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OACgL.png)

environment
Detox version: 19.13.0
React Native version: 0.65.1
Node version: 14.21.2 (pipeline) 16.17.1 (laptop)
Device model: Azure Pipelines/Mac
OS: Mac OS 12.6.2(pipeline)/12.6.2(laptop)
Test-runner (select one): Other